# Black bar header, condensed font

Tags: templates

Very often I see LaTeX typset documents which have a header similar to [this](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61a/sp13/exams/61a-sp13-quiz.pdf):

[image]

The header is sandwiched by a double black bar and has a distinctive skinny  font.

What is used to achieve this effect?

Comment: To produce a rule you can use `\rule[lift]{width}{thickness}`.

Comment: Are you interested in the effect of the font or of the rules or of both? In fact, is the font of importance to the question?

Comment: For font information, see [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](http://goo.gl/YsWvA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing document properties, the "skinny" font is identified as CMDUNH10, so you can say something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand\lgh{\fontsize{17}{21}\usefont{T1}{cmdh}{m}{n}}
\newcommand\myrule{\par\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{4pt}\par}

\begin{document}

\myrule\medskip
\noindent{\lgh CS61A\hfill Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs \\[0.5ex]
Spring 2013}\hfill{\scshape Quiz}
\myrule

\end{document}
```

[image]